# React JS app with styled components not scrolling when using display grid and padding

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

So, I have this TSX file and this styled div container linked to it. The idea is that I have a card that depending on the content height should scroll or stay centered. So far it stays centered but when the content overflows it doesn't scroll. Does anyone know what can be done?

```
import React from 'react';

import { Container } from './styles';

export const Notification: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <div className="card">
        <div className="box" />
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Container = styled.div`
  padding: 32px 48px;
  min-height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;

  .card {
    background: white;
    padding: 20px 24px;

    .box {
      height: 1500px;
      background: red;
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: use `overflow: auto;`

Comment: I've tried adding it already but didn't really do anything

Answer (score 0):

Try manipulating the [overflow property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) on the element in question to scroll

Comment: I've tried adding it already but didn't really do anything